# How to create equivalence class from an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am working on `matlab` and have an array:

```
a =   
2 1 5 3 2 1 2 1
```

You can see there may be one value multiple times. I want a function that will give me an array for each of those value that contains the **index(s)** of that value in the array as output.

Using the above example, the output would be:

```
(1 5 7)
(2 6 8)
(3) 
(4)
```

(1 5 7) are the indexes of 2 in the input array. Same happens for 1,5 and 3.

This can be done using `for loops` etc. I just want to know if there is some in-built function for this in `matlab`.

****  **EDIT**  ****

There may be two columns as following.

```
2 1 5 3 2 1 2 1
3 4 3 2 4 4 3 4
```

In that case output will be

```
(1 7)
(2 6 8)
(3)
(4)
(5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third output of [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get unique labels for each column of `a`, and then apply [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function:

```
[~, ~, kk] = unique(a.', 'rows', 'stable'); %'
result = accumarray(kk, (1:numel(kk)).', [], @(x) {sort(x).'});
```

This works for any number of rows. For your two-row example

```
a = [2 1 5 3 2 1 2 1
     3 4 3 2 4 4 3 4];
```

the result is

```
result{1} =
     1     7
result{2} =
     2     6     8
result{3} =
     3
result{4} =
     4
result{5} =
     5
```

If element order is not important, you can simplify the code a little:

```
[~, ~, kk] = unique(a.', 'rows'); %'
result = accumarray(kk, (1:numel(kk)).', [], @(x) {x.'});
```

which gives

```
result{1} =
     2     8     6
result{2} =
     7     1
result{3} =
     5
result{4} =
     4
result{5} =
     3
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a buit-in function to do that, but you can do it in one line with `unique` and `arrayfun:`

```
Res = arrayfun(@(x) find(x==a), unique (x, 'stable'), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Best,

Comment: Sure, but I don't get how you obtain this output with multiple lines. How do you define the ouput ?

Comment: here I am considering column number. For 1st and 7th Columns are same, so `(1 7)` . 2nd, 6th, 8th columns are same, so `(2,6,8)` . so on ...

Answer (score 2):

Extend Ratbert's nice answer to arrive at a more general one which addresses the "edited" request:

```
[~, ~, J]= unique(a.', 'rows');
Res = cellfun(@str2num,accumarray(J,[1:size(a,2)]',[], @(x)num2str(x),'uni',0);
```

Use of conversion from double to char and back is clunky, but it works with Octave 3.6.4, and should also work on MATLAB. In MATLAB a more elegant answer with accumarray is likely possible.

---

Edit: The following is a more elegant answer with `accumarray` (see the MATLAB documentation for more details) - equivalent to LuisMendo's answer.

```
[~, ~, J]= unique(a.', 'rows');
Res = accumarray(J,[1:numel(J)]',[],@(x){x});
```